# Incompatible Type issue with templatization

Tags: java, generics, java-8

i got stuck into templatization issue. Code is working fine on my office computer but not working on my personal laptop

Code :

```
public <T> List<T> convert(List<String> values, Class<T> expectedClass) {
        if (expectedClass == String.class) {
            return values;
        }
}
```

This code shows this error:

```
Incompatible Types.
     Required: List<T>
     Found: List<java.lang.String>
```

I could not understand why this code is working on my office computer not on my personal laptop.
Can anyone help me please!

Comment: Are you sure it worked at the office? Uncasted return value should always fail to compile. Missing return statement after if statement should always fail to compile.

Comment: “templatization” is a misleading term. Java doesn’t have templates.

Answer (score -1):

I'm **certain** that this doesn't work on your work machine, either.  The reason for this is twofold: due to the invariance of generics; a `List<T>` is in no way, shape or form the same as a `List<String>`.

You're also missing a return statement.  But that's a minor detail in the face of the generics problem.

As written, the only conceivable way that this could work is if you had some way to turn a `String` to an unbound type through some process, but I'm not sure how you'd fabricate one of those without a *lot* of `instanceof` statements.

From the inference here, it's really tough to say what you were intending to do here.  Perhaps you *were* trying to convert a `List<String>` into something more generic, but from a conceptual standpoint, that sounds infeasible.

I would encourage you to reconsider the design of this method, since it's busted and conceptually flawed.